# EPPlus - How to print column captions and not column names

Tags: .net, excel, epplus

I am using the fantabulous EPPlus component in my .net program. I have my data in a DataTable and fill my excel spreadsheet like this:

```
ws.Cells["A3"].LoadFromDataTable(newTable, true, TableStyles.Medium9);
```

However, the column headers print out the names of my columns and not the translated captions.

In theory I could simply use change the column names prior to calling the code above, but in practice I have columns with identical captions which isn't allowed as names.

My last resort is to change the cell values after the above code has run, but I'd rather not.

Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: and now I've tried changing the columns manually but it wont stick. strange..

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to recompile the code changing line 1542 in ExcelRangeBase.cs

```
_worksheet.Cell(row, col++).Value = dc.ColumnName;
```

to something like >>

```
_worksheet.Cell(row, col++).Value = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dc.Caption) ? dc.ColumnName : dc.Caption;
```

Cheers,